# Creating a macro to click links on a webpage, if a certain web-page loads?

Tags: macros, web

My ISP (T-Mobile 3G, due to living in rural England) redirects all web-pages to a T-Zone page every time I use 250MB of data. As a result, I cannot download large files overnight as after 250MB has passed, the download is 'paused', and if I try and load any web-pages, the previously mentioned page loads. **To remove the page, you simply have to click 2 links saying you wish to get a 'free booster'.**

Is there any way I could automatically macro this to happen in the background, or perhaps on one of my secondary machines?

I can provide pages of the web-page in question, if it helps anyone give me suggestions on how to create such a macro. :-)

Comment: What operating system are you using ?

Comment: Windows 8 x64 on my main machine, although I can run either Ubuntu 12.10 or Windows 7 x32 on my laptop.

Comment: I suggest you use a broswer add-on like [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/firebug/) to see the exact data sent when you click on the "free booster" button, and then recreate the same request using a Python script (which will work both on Windows and on Ubuntu), and finally leave the script running in background which will send the request every once in a while to keep the connection online.

Comment: Is there any documentation on how to find out the exact data sent from a button on a web-page when clicked using FireBug?